# vagrant + aws: error downloading 'dummy'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vagrant, vagrantfile

I am literally using the defaults in the getting started given at https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws. I set the access/secret keys + keypair to use environment variables:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "dummy"

  config.vm.provider :aws do |aws, override|
    aws.access_key_id = ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY']
    aws.secret_access_key = ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']
    #aws.session_token = "SESSION TOKEN"
    aws.keypair_name = ENV['AWS_KEYPAIR']

    aws.ami = "ami-7747d01e"

    override.ssh.username = "ubuntu"
    override.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/id_rsa"
  end
end
```

I run `vagrant up --provider=aws`:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'aws' provider...
==> default: Box 'dummy' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: aws
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'dummy' (v0) for provider: aws
    default: Downloading: dummy
An error occurred while downloading the remote file. The error
message, if any, is reproduced below. Please fix this error and try
again.

Couldn't open file /Users/username/vagrants/ec2test/dummy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `dummy` box, vagrant will not be able to find this box and download it from atlas.

make sure to add the box yourself

```
vagrant box add dummy https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box
```

After this, it will work better

Answer (score 2):

For a more portable solution, add this line to your config (below `config.vm.box`):

```
config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/raw/master/dummy.box"
```